# Split and inner join return string in row SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, split, inner-join

I have 2 tables:

**Table1**

```
 ID    Name    
 ------------
  1    Cpu        
  2    Vga        
  3    Ram
```

**Table2** :

```
 ID   Names      
 -------------
  1   1;2             
  2   1;2;3           
  3   2
```

I want result: Select in table 2 :

```
 ID    Names     Names string  
 ----------------------------
  1    1;2       Cpu,Vga         
  2    1;2;3     Cpu,Vga,Ram     
  3    2         Vga
```

How to solve my problem? Thank you

Comment: Are these your actual tables, or are they stripped down examples?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This here will do the trick for you.

You need to create a function which can split out your rows so you can join them afterwards and use som XML to concat your rows back.

**You need to create a function which can split your rows or unconcat**

```
    CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[dba_parseString_udf] (
      @stringToParse VARCHAR(8000)  
    , @delimiter     CHAR(1)
)
RETURNS @parsedString TABLE (stringValue VARCHAR(128)) AS
BEGIN

/* Declare variables */
DECLARE @trimmedString  VARCHAR(8000);

/* We need to trim our string input in case the user entered extra spaces */
SET @trimmedString = LTRIM(RTRIM(@stringToParse));

/* Let's create a recursive CTE to break down our string for us */
WITH parseCTE (StartPos, EndPos)
AS
(
    SELECT 1 AS StartPos
        , CHARINDEX(@delimiter, @trimmedString + @delimiter) AS EndPos
    UNION ALL
    SELECT EndPos + 1 AS StartPos
        , CHARINDEX(@delimiter, @trimmedString + @delimiter , EndPos + 1) AS EndPos
    FROM parseCTE
    WHERE CHARINDEX(@delimiter, @trimmedString + @delimiter, EndPos + 1) <> 0
)

/* Let's take the results and stick it in a table */  
INSERT INTO @parsedString
SELECT SUBSTRING(@trimmedString, StartPos, EndPos - StartPos)
FROM parseCTE
WHERE LEN(LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTRING(@trimmedString, StartPos, EndPos - StartPos)))) > 0
OPTION (MaxRecursion 8000);

RETURN;   
END
```

> Inner table here is your Table2 and split table is your table1

**SQL Code to run**

```
    with result as (
SELECT  [id]
      ,[name]
      ,i.stringValue
from [LegOgSpass].[dbo].[inner] as  a
  cross apply [dbo].[dba_parseString_udf](a.Name,';') i
  )

  ,partresult as (
  select a.id,a.name,b.name as RowstoConcat from result a
  left join LegOgSpass.dbo.split b on a.stringValue = b.id
  )
    SELECT id,Name, Pets = STUFF((SELECT N', ' + RowstoConcat 
  FROM partresult AS p2
   WHERE p2.name = p.name 
   ORDER BY RowstoConcat
   FOR XML PATH(N'')), 1, 2, N'')
FROM partresult AS p
GROUP BY id,Name
ORDER BY id,Name
```

**Result**

[image]

Comment: Thanks plaidDK, problem solve

Answer (score 0):

```
;WITH cte AS (
SELECT * FROM Table1 t1
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT id AS t2_id, VALUE AS nameid
    FROM Table2 t2
    CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(Names,';') 
    ) t3
ON t1.id=t3.nameid
) 
SELECT id ,
    STUFF((SELECT ','+ Name FROM cte c2 where c.id =c2.t2_id FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'' ) 
    AS [Name String],

    STUFF ((SELECT ','+ cast(t2_id as varchar) from cte c2 
    WHERE c.id=c2.nameid FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'' ) AS Names
FROM cte c
GROUP BY id
```

**OUTPUT**

```
id    Name String    Names
1     Cpu,Vga         1,2
2     Cpu,Vga,Ram     1,2,3
3     Vga             2
```

**NOTE**

As @plaidDK pointed out in comments that,

`STRING_SPLIT()` is not a function of `SQL SERVER 2008`, the above query will help if you find some Stored procedures to do the  functionality of `STRING_SPLIT()` .
And Substitute `STRING_SPLIT()` with Stored procedure name

Comment: string split is not a function in SQL Server 2008

Comment: @plaidDK Thanks for the info. May be he can use a stored procedure to do do the functionality of `string_split`.

Comment: thanks jophab, i will use sql 2012 ^^